# Are memory space requirements for my application equal to how many variables/arrays (and the likes) I use?

Tags: php, performance, memory, requirements

Are memory space requirements for my application equal to the space required by all variables/arrays (and the likes) I use or declare? I'm talking about PHP mainly, but i'd like to know if, in general, this is valid to other languages. I think the following code has  memory requirements lower than the code right below it. That's because the 2nd code uses a third variable "result", while the first one has only 2 variables.

```
<?php
$x = 10;
$y = 7;

echo "$x+$y = ";
echo $x+$y;
echo "<br>";

echo "$x-$y = ";
echo $x-$y;
echo "<br>";

echo "$x*$y = ";
echo $x*$y;
echo "<br>";

echo "$x/$y = ";
echo $x/$y;
echo "<br>";

echo "$x%$y = ";
echo $x%$y;
echo "<br>";

?>
```

Second code:

```
<?php

$x=10; 
$y=7; 

$result=$x+$y; 
echo "$x + $y = $result<br />";   

$result=$x-$y; 
echo "$x - $y = $result<br />";   

$result=$x*$y; 
echo "$x * $y = $result<br />";   

$result=$x/$y; 
echo "$x / $y = $result<br />";   

$result=$x%$y; 
echo "$x % $y = $result<br />";   

?>
```

So is that true? Are memory space requirements for my application equal to the space required by all variables/arrays (and the likes) I use or declare? Which one of the codes consumes less memory?

Comment: Well, the code itself (or whatever machine representation it produces) does take up some memory too, and there's also a bit of operating system overhead.  Strings take up some memory, etc.

Comment: Why not measure it? Yes, every variable takes up memory space while it's in scope, but so do a whole host of other things, including the script itself.... but unless you're really tightly restricted in your memory limits, then it's more important that code should be readable

Comment: For PHP you can use the [memory_get_peak_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) function to determine how much memory your script uses.

Comment: Note that PHP uses "copy-on-write" which means `$a = 5; $b = $a` will sensibly use the same amount of memory, while `$a = 5; $b = $a + 5` will use twice the space. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php for internal variables behaviors